# How to insertMany and update duplicates in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert, insert-update

I have many orders I would like to insert in MongoDB, the orders are unique indexed by orderID.

I would like to insert all the orders and update order time if one of my order was exists in the database.

I have tried to use updateMany with upsert set to true, but it didn't work as expected.

```
static async addOrders(ordersArray) {
    const ordersTable = new mongoose.model('ordersTable', Schemas.ordersTable);

    try {
        const docs = await ordersTable.insertMany(ordersArray, {ordered: false});
        return Promise.resolve('Data Inserted');
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find duplicates as follows, then you can remove them and insert them again.

example:

```
static async addOrders(ordersArray) {
const ordersTable = new mongoose.model('ordersTable', Schemas.ordersTable);

try {
    const docs = await ordersTable.insertMany(ordersArray, {ordered: false});
    return Promise.resolve('Data Inserted');
} catch (e) {
       if (e.code === 11000){
            // 1- getting duplicates
            console.log('getting duplicates');

            let orders = [];
            const ordersIDs = e.result.result.writeErrors.map(error=>{
                const parsedError = JSON.stringify(error);
                const order = JSON.parse(parsedError).op;
                orders.push(order);
                return order.orderID;
            });
            // 2- removing old duplicates.
            const deleted = await ordersTable.deleteMany({orderID:{'$in':ordersIDs}});
            // 3- adding the orders
            try{

                const newAddedOrders = await ordersTable.insertMany(orders , {ordered : false});
                return Promise.resolve('Data Inserted');
            }catch (e) {
                return Promise.reject(e);
            }


        }else return Promise.reject(e);

}
```

}

As you see in the code comments, we are getting duplicates first, then we are removing and inserting the rows.